# Are consecutive zeros across multiple dimensions in multivariate time series a problem when estimating VARMA models?

Tags: time-series, estimation, arima, autocorrelation, zero-inflation

I want to estimate a VARMA model for a 14-dimensional multivariate time series (Fig. 1, 2). The goal is to investigate how the trajectory of my alleged output time series (messages per hour; Fig. 1, top left) relates to the alleged input time series (several variables concerning the content of said messages per hour).

As you can see from the plots, in some periods no messages were observed (i. e. no missing observations but complete, equidistant observations, some of which are 0). Consequently, the values for the other time series are also 0—as no observations can be made about the messages' content when there are no messages.

My question: What implications do these zeroes have for the estimation of VARMA models? Will there be problems due to autocorrelations between periods with zeroes and synchronous and cross correlations between time series for periods with zeroes? And if so: How would I overcome them?
[image: Fig. 1: Time Series Plots]
[image: Fig. 2: Time Series Plots (continued)]